# C passing a pointer to an array on the stack

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am getting confused as to whether it is valid (in C) to pass a pointer to an array that has been initiated as follows (e.g. at compile time on the stack):

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

my_func(&a);


void my_func(int **a)
{
   int *tmp = *a; /* this statement fixes the problem */
   printf("%d %d %d", (*a)[0], (*a)[1], (*a)[2]); /*doesn't work */ 
   printf("%d %d %d", tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]); /*does work */ 
}
```

when I step through this with gdb I can't 'see' any of the values (*a)[0], etc. from 'inside' my_func. e.g.

```
(gdb) p (*a)[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

I'm thinking that possibly I have a fundamental misunderstanding with regard to what you can and can't do with arrays that are on the stack rather than the heap?

I hope thats not the case as it is very convenient for my unit tests to declare arrays on the stack as in the example, but I need to test functions that are expecting pointers to pointers to int.

Note I do get a compiler warning as follows:

```
 test_utility.c:499:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘int_array_unique’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 ../src/glamdring2.h:152:5: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[12]’
```

but I thought it would be ok to mix int `*a[]` with `**a`? Perhaps not? Are they not equivalent?

Comment: If you want to store the pointer on the stack you could cast it before storing it and cast it again when you want to use it: `ptr_int = (int)ptr` for storage of `ptr_int` and `ptr = (int*)ptr_int` for usage. But i'm not sure whether this is sufficient for your problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you pass a reference to the array pointer?

Comment: @kenneth yes - i am using the parameter as both an input and return value.

Comment: I have a fix, needed an appropriate cast in my_func, int *tmp_a = *a; and everything starts working.

Comment: basically, I don't know my lvalues from my rvalues as pointed out by wildplasser. Hopefully rectifying that with some background reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a[] is an array, not a pointer ("not an lvalue"); in your function call

```
func( &a);
```

&a decays to a pointer to int; &a is **not** a pointer to pointer to int. Why? **there is no pointer** to point to.

The function prototype

```
void func( int **p);
```

expects a pointer to pointer to int, that does not fit the function being called with a pointer to int as an argument, like you did.

UPDATE: I don't know what the OP's intentions were, so this is just a guess...

```
void my_func(int *a);

int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

my_func(a); /* note: this is equivalent to my_func( &a ); */


void my_func(int *a)
{
   printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2] ); 
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure `&a` is of  type `int*`?

Comment: It *is* not a pointer to int, it *decays* into one. (because there is no pointer to point to, the pointer to array decays to pointer to 1st element)

Comment: Yes, of course I meant decaying. Well I didn't know that, but it makes perfect sense, since a pointer to the array is indeed a pointer to the first element. I never used `&a` anyway, so never really thought about it. +1.

Comment: @wildplasser I think you have probably provided the answer there but I can't understand it. Any chance you could illustrate your point with an example? e.g. bearing in mind what you have said, what code would be required to get it to work?

Comment: @wildplasser ok - so you can't pass in a pointer to a and then hope to dereference within the function to retrieve the array elements?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is write a 'unique' function that can return an array where all duplicates have been removed. I have totally confused myself in the process.

Comment: In that case you'll at least have to supply an extra argument to the function with the number of elements that is can expect in the arrray. The function knows nothing about the array, only the (type and) address of the first element.

Comment: @wildplasser could I ask what your function prototype would look like for such a function? Mine is currently: `void int_array_unique(int **array, size_t *n). I'm using array as both the input and the output array and n as both the input and output array lengths.

Comment: Voila! That's the power of K&R2 / ANSI / c89 / c90: the function declaration / definition are exactly the same (plus or minus a ';' )

Comment: @wildplasser ok, very last question - I think you're implying that this is covered in K&R. I've searched the K&R index for unique, remove, duplicates to no avail. If you could give me the page number I will be eternally grateful

Comment: Now you'r talking semantics; I was only trying to help you understanding the syntax. To remove duplicates, you'll need to inspect every element of the array. This is a (N*(N-1))/2 process. You could speed it up by sorting, that will make it a (N-1)+ (N*log(N)) process. You do the coding. Post your results, and somebody will surely comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%p vs %p vs %p\n",&a,&a[0],a);
```

&a &a[0] and a - are all the same - the address of the first int in the array

```
void my_func(int **a);
int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *p = a;
    printf("%p vs %p vs %p\n",&a,&a[0],a); //are all the same - the address of the first int in the array
    my_func(&p);
    return 0;
}
void my_func(int **a) {
    printf("%d %d %d", (*a)[0], (*a)[1], (*a)[2]);
}
```

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to declare an array on the stack and pass its address to a function, so long as the function doesn't try to store a reference to the array for later use.

Not sure why you're adding the extra indirection to the the argument, though. Why not just declare `my_func` to take an `int*` as a parameter, and simply pass `a` as the argument? This is less likely to confuse the debugger.

Comment: thats exactly what I thought. I can't understand why I can't dereference the pointer in gdb?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *)`. This might not be true. I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but at least I would start by either adding a runtime test asserting the assumption, or probably better change from int to pointer.